# Rear tire rubbing on both chainstays

Tags: tire, aluminum

I left my bike in our boiler room over the winter, and now the back tire is rubbing heavily on both chain stays.  Before it was a very tight clearance, but it worked without a problem.  Now, it heavily rubs on both sides at all times, so it is neither a centering nor a trueness issue.  My only theory a is that it has to do with the fact that the boiler room was pretty hot ~96 degrees, and over the winter either the aluminum tubes or the tire expanded.  Is this plausible? do you guys have any other solutions? The bike is a '95 Cannondale road bike, works perfectly otherwise.

Comment: Is this in one spot, or the entire circumference of the tire?   Is it a horizontal dropout and the wheel shifted forward?

Comment: The entire circumference, I checked the dropouts and they're all the way back

Comment: I would guess that the tire is failing.  Probably it's the wrong size for that bike, though.

Comment: What nominal size/width was the tyre?  I own a similar age canoodle, and can barely fit 28 but ended up dropping to 25 because of rub.

Comment: If you had some calipers, you could measure the actual inflated width of your tyre as it is on your bike now, I bet it has stretched

Comment: Cannot imagine a tire failing in a way that it gets wide around the entire circumference.  96 degree is not particularly hot and unlikely to affect a tire that much, and  certainly not the casing which is typically made of something like nylon or Kevlar.  No way could a warm room affect the frame.  Is there any possibility the bike could have suffered mechanical damage while stored, and the frame was crushed?

Compare the width of the front tire to the rear - are they the same? Put the front tire on the rear wheel, does the problem go away (Presuming the tires are the same size)

Comment: Are we talking 96°C or Fahrenheit?

Comment: I presumed 96  Fahrenheit.

Comment: I wonder if the bikes have horizontal dropouts and the whole wheel has moved forward to a narrower point in the chain stays

Comment: I would assume the boiler room is not 204°F... If the tires were aired up in cold or extreme cold, and then moved to an especially hot room for storage it could be that the pressure in the tube is significantly higher than it is supposed to be, and if the tire was already very close to the frame maybe this was enough to cause it to rub?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the aluminum would not expand, for all intents and purposes, so that leaves the tire as the cause.  If it were exposed to high temperatures for an extended length of time then the tire could start to deteriorate (rubber, tire cords) to cause it to not contain the air pressure within the same volume, i.e., enlarging the tire.  An extreme example of this can be seen when a bike is carried on a rear rack on a vehicle, where the bike tire is in line with the exhaust pipe on the vehicle.  Over time, the bike tire will swell and eventually burst due to the heat.

Other things to consider: are there any other chemicals or fumes that are in the boiler room?  If there are any caustic or acidic fumes (even minor ones) in a hot environment they could have a deteriorating effect on rubber or other compounds.